# Shower Ruining Bathroom Walls

Tags: bathroom, water, drywall, shower, leak

walk in shower is slowly creating a hole in the surrounding wall.  it is not a big issue, but something that I would like to fix for aesthetic purposes.  any recommendations on how I would fix the wall and then prevent this from happening again?

Comment: A shower creating a hole in a wall is a big issue. Can you provide some pictures?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you.

Comment: I've used fiberglass-reinforced plastic panels for shower walls, e.g. https://www.lowes.com/pd/48-in-x-8-ft-Embossed-White-Wall-Panel/1000174771